# Hosting powershell inside ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, powershell

I hope this doesn't fall into the non question category.

I would like to host a powershell environment inside my ASP.NET application, running in the same process as the Application Pool, and be able to remotely connect to the hosted environment. I already have a dll with my custom Cmdlets that I would also like to use inside my hosted session.

Note that I'm not just looking to run arbitrary commands inside ASP.NET. Instead, I want to have a full shell like interface where I can work in.

I've looked at fan-in and creating/pooling Runspaces, but this is too vague and I can't seem to find good information on this specific scenario. So any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: What? You want powershell remoting but the remote shell is hosted in an IIS worker process instead of WinRM server endpoint? That makes zero sense. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PowerShellASP - part of the product suite listed at http://www.powershellinside.com. That should allow you to host PowerShell with ASP.NET.  Another option (if you want to mix ASP.NET and PowerShell in the same page) would be the PowerShell Panel: 
http://www.powershellinside.com/powershell/panel/